# Moving data from one web form to another ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to move the content of a textbox on the from StudentRegistration to the form MyProfile by following a tutorial on YouTube. However when I try to reference the StudentRegitration Page in my code, I get the error that the type or namespace cannot be found.

In the tutorial I can see that in their code they have a namespace, however my website does not. Could anyone tell me what to do in order to be able to reference StudentRegistration without getting an error?

I should have stated that I have a website not a web app. I have found that websites do not have a default namespace. How would I go about accessing the StudentRegistration without referencing a namespace?

```
public partial class MyProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

       if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
           StudentRegistration LastPage = (StudentRegistration)Context.Handler;

           lblEmail.Text = StudentRegistration.STextBoxEm;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: That is an issue with references. You do not have a reference to the StudentRegistration class. Add a reference to it with the Using statement or write out the entire thing - like <your namespace>.StudentRegistration

Comment: Thanks. I am new to programming and I don't think my project actually has a namespace. Is there a way I can create one? If I type Using StudentRegistration I get the error that it doesnt exist in the current context.

Comment: If you are using C# your classes should always have a namespace. So if your project name is "Registration" - then your namespace is Registration. And your class is referenced as Registration.StudentRegistration. Are you using Visual Studio? Usually the structure for classes in C# will be namespace <namespace> { class classname {} }

Comment: I should have stated that I am working on a website. The class is structured as public partial class MyProfile : System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: it shouldn't matter if you are working on a website, classes are still classes and this particular class is the code behind your page.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answer your question directly, I'd like to point out another issue with your code that will probably prevent it from working. You should refer to the documentation on the `PreviousPage` property at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It does **NOT** work like this:

1. user visits /StudentRegistration.aspx
2. user does stuff
3. user submits the form on /StudentRegistration.aspx
4. server redirects the user to /MyProfile.aspx
5. MyProfile class knows that `PreviousPage` = the class from /StudentRegistration.aspx

Instead, the description from the msdn reference page linked above stipulates that the `PreviousPage` property only works on this scenario:

1. user visits /StudentRegistration.aspx
2. user does some stuff
3. user submits form on /StudentRegistration.aspx
4. server **transfers** request to the MyProfile class

   - this does not mean that the url has changed to /MyProfile.aspx for the user, this means that the server is going to treat the current request to /StudentRegistration.aspx **as if** it were actually a request to /MyProfile.aspx
5. the user ends up seeing the result of what would normally be /MyProfile.aspx on /StudentRegistration.aspx

Now, your code may actually want that, but the fact that you have:

`if (PreviousPage != null)
{
    StudentRegistration LastPage = (StudentRegistration)Context.Handler;
    // this should be 
    // StudentRegistration LastPage = (StudentRegistration)PreviousPage;
}`

makes me think that you have misinterpreted the somewhat misleadingly named `PreviousPage` property. For a sample of how to persist state across multiple page loads in .NET, I would recommend reading up on SessionState. It has a somewhat complicated name, but does more of what you would want in this scenario:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

An added bonus is that you do not need to reference one class from another, so you fix your current bug later on. Additionally, even if you did resolve your potential namespace error, the issue that I outlined earlier will cause the value of the text field to be blank if your code is working as I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You are *sending* data from a source to a target - e.g. StudentRegistration -> MyProfile

You have options because at the end of the day, it is HTTP. Aside from "persistence" (Session), and the tutorial you are following, a "simpler" way is to use [`ButtonPostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

All it means is that you are `POST`ing data to the target page. The target page (MyProfile) will have to validate and parse the posted data (`Request.Form`). This way you don't have to manage things like Session state.